# pgp decryption of file encrypted from named pipe as input does not decrypt to execution directory

Tags: encryption

if I encrypt data (via gpg) in the form of a flat file, on decryption (via pgp and with out specifying output directory) the decrypted file will write to the execution directory.

If I encrypt data read from a named pipe, on decryption the decrypted file will write to the landed directory and not the execution directory.  This happens in a windows2003 environment.

Does anyone have any suggestions (other than specifying output directory in the decrypt command) on how to get around this behavior?  Or an explanation of what might be happening?  The end consumer of the data employs code that expects the file to write to the execution directory and would like to avoid any code changes.

lynux

```
encrypt:cat named_pipe | gpg -r XXXXXXX -q --yes -e > encrypted_file.pgp
```

windows2003

```
pushd \desired\directory
decrypt: pgp --decrypt \landed\directory\encrypted_file.pgp -v --overwrite wipe --passphrase "password"
```